# Performance benefit when using less files for same amount of classes?

Tags: java

Is there any performance difference in my application if I change the number of files of source code (without changing anything in the code itself)? I mean, if, for example, I put all my classes in just 1 file (without new relationships, as static classes), instead 50, will this have a performance benefit (or drawback)?

Just wondering...

The question is not about mantainability. I just want to know if this increases performance or not (and why).

Comment: It won't have any significant effect on performance, and it will have a disastrous effect on maintainability. Anyway, all public classes must be in their own file.

Comment: If you're curious about performance, why not *measure it* both ways? Elapsed time is one of the most readily observable things about computer programs...

Comment: @JBNizet as stated I'm just curious about the performance. Greg, it's faster to ask here, instead writing myself a benchmark... and I'm asking also for the reason, that's something I will probably not find out myself.

Comment: I understand that, but the question is just silly. That's like asking if your car will run faster if you cut your legs. You won't do it anyway.

Comment: I don't know well how the compiler works... and I wasn't clear about each class getting a .class file at runtime, with this knowledge it's a legitimate question...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It may have a (negligible) impact on the performance of the compiler while it builds your project. After that it is irrelevant, since what is actually run is the class files produced by the compiler.

A more interesting question is whether there is a performance difference at runtime between having the class files in a directory hierarchy and having them in a JAR file (which again could be compressed or uncompressed). Having them in an uncompressed JAR file is probably fastest, but this will only impact startup time, and probably not much.

Once an application has started, class definition are kept in memory, and where they were stored does not matter.

In terms of PHP (which is what I guess this question comes from), Java always and implicitly uses a bytecode cache.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, all classes will result in distinct `*.class` files being created, regardless of how they're laid out in the code.

Thus any performance benefits would be restricted to the compilation phase only, because the resulting classes/JAR would be identical at runtime.

(And you'll be unlikely to see significant/noticeable performance improvements even here.  Certainly not ones that would make it worthwhile to lay out your code in an unnatural way.  Just write code that makes sense and is understandable, and trust the compiler to turn it into bytecode sensibly.)

Answer (score 1):

With 'clever classloading' the 'big class' will suffer a performance hit at start-up. *Especially* if it is deployed using something like [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) (which can **download,** cache and load classes as needed).

As to the run-time impact - the performance once loaded, I'll leave that to others.

Answer (score 1):

The question is pretty moot, since in most cases its *not possible*. You can't put two public classes into the same .java file (the compiler will complain).
For non-public classes, its possible, but it has *no* effect on the bytecode generated for those classes sharing the same source file.

If you put multiple classes as static classes into an enclosing class, this will result in longer class names in the generated bytecode, but the performance of the code in the actual classes will still be the same.

Comment: yes, it's actually about putting static classes in an enclosing class. It's the nearest way to emulate "public" being in the same file, I guess.